# Can I read an `export`ed variable from a python script?

Tags: python, bash, inheritance, export

I have a bash script and a python script:

**script**

```
#!/bin/bash
a=10
export a
python script.py
```

**script.py**

```
# access 'a' somehow
```

Is there a way to access the `export`ed variables from python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exported variables are set as environment variables. Use [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ) (a dictionary) to read these in your Python script:

```
import os

a = os.environ['a']
```

Comment: You can keep the upvote :)

Comment: @TomFenech: why thank you! I already hit the cap today, if that matters. :-)